# how to echo input text in For{}

Tags: php, html

I write below code and put an html input text in for :

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
 echo '<input type="text" name="subject">';
```

but when i want to echo the that value I type in to the above text box 
it returns *""* *nothing*

```
echo $_POST['subject'];
```

I have

```
<form name="form1"  method="post" action="index.php">
```

Tag top of this codes ?

*Sorry if I had Mistake*

Comment: ```echo $_POST['subject']``` is on the ```.php``` page where the form action points to?

Comment: you are naming all the input fields as subject. whats the use of doing this?

Comment: @iyop45  yes its on php page . and form action is ok .thats index.php

Comment: Looks like all your input names are subject. This doesn't look right. Show your HTML code. Also, please specify what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @coder no  im useing that on html table

Comment: @ObjectManipulator yes this html text name is same

Comment: That doesn't look right. If you have 5 input boxes, they are not supposed to have the same name.

Comment: @Mohammadalimirahamed, please post your code so that we can help u

Comment: `$_POST['subject']` will show the value of the *last* input if they all have the same name.

Comment: this is my code i put in the question

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ??

Comment: if i make dynamic name for html text . next how can i get that for return ??

Comment: @SameerK i have just 5 html text with  for{} with same name all of html text . and i want to echo each of these  inputs Fills with value !!

Comment: @Mohammadalimirahamed It's hard to understand what you actually want to achieve. I assume you want to show five input fields; and then show the values for each input field once the form is submitted. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the input as array and read the values in PHP using loop like below.

HTML code :

```
<form name='myForm' action='index.php' method="post">
     <?php
     for {$i=i;$i<5;$i++} {
           echo "<input type='text' name='subject[]'>";
     }
    ?>  
</form>
```

PHP Code :

```
$subjectArray = $_POST['subject'];
foreach($subjectArray as $key => $val) {
     if($val != "") {  
         echo $key."==".$val."<br>";
     }
}
```

Comment: ?how can i do that ??

Comment: sorry i did not get your statement.  Do you want show the data in these dynamic input box ? or do you want to fetch the data entered in these boxes in PHP file ??. Between i updated my answer and tested it. It shows all the values entered via these input boxes in PHP file.

Comment: PHP file will get all the text box values in this case irrespective of whether values are entered for all text boxes or for few text boxes. So added if condition to show only input fields which have values. See the updated answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks . its not actually my answer . but it working . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's bad manner to `echo` your HTML code. It can become annoyingly hard for someone to read the code after you (for exemple, in a company)

I would suggest doing this:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    ?><input type="text" name="subject"><?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to input back in the form what was just typed, then you're doing too much. 
Is your form in index.php too?! If so, `action="index.php"` become `action=""`

• With your array:

```
$subjectArray= array();
// Gather data from $_POST if it's the subject form
if(!empty($_POST) aa isset $_POST['subjectForm']) {
    // Remove the hidden input from the list
    unset($_POST['subjectForm']);
    // Add the remaining entry to $subjectArray
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $subjectArray[$key]= $value;
    }
}

<form name="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <!-- hidden input to find our form after validation -->
    <input type="hidden" name="subjectForm" value=1>
    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
        ?><input type="text" name="subject<?= $i ?>" value="<?php if(isset(subjectArray['subject'.$i])) { echo $_POST['subjectArray'.$i]; } ?>"><?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

• Without your array:

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    ?><input type="text" name="subject<?= $i ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subject'.$i])) { echo $_POST['subjectArray'.$i]; } ?>"><?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```